# ToggleFade an element with display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle fade a login box when a 'login' button is pressed. Until the 'login' button is pressed I want the box to be hidden with `display: none` so that it can't be seen or interacted with (I wasn't sure if having no visibility will prevent its buttons from being clicked - maybe pointer events could be altered though).

The toggle works perfectly fine except for the first time the button is pressed in which the hide class is removed (displaying the box) but then the toggle fades OUT the box.

HTML:

```
<a id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" href="/">Login</a>
<div id="loginContainer" class="loginContainer hide">
    <a class="registerBtn" href="/">Register</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loginBtn {
    color: #1493d1;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 98px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
    text-decoration: none;
}

.loginContainer {
    width: 175px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
}

.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginBtn");

    //DISPLAY MOBILE NAVIGATION ON HAMBURGER CLICK
    function displayLogin() {
        $('#loginContainer').removeClass("hide");
        $('#loginContainer').fadeToggle("fast");
    }

    //EVENT LISTENERS
    loginBtn.addEventListener("click", displayLogin);

}); //Doc Ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below mentioned solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginBtn");

    //DISPLAY MOBILE NAVIGATION ON HAMBURGER CLICK
    function displayLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginContainer').fadeToggle("fast");
        $('#loginContainer').removeClass("hide");
    }

    //EVENT LISTENERS
    loginBtn.addEventListener("click", displayLogin);

});
```

```css
.loginBtn {
    color: #1493d1;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 98px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
    text-decoration: none;
}

.loginContainer {
    width: 175px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0px;
    /*float: right;*/
}

.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" href="/">Login</a>
<div id="loginContainer" class="loginContainer hide">
    <a class="registerBtn" href="/">Register</a>
</div>
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Unfortunatley doesn't work, did you change anything other than adding the prevent default?

Comment: Please check my answer again, I have added e.preventDefault and changed position of adding class below. `e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginContainer').fadeToggle("fast");
        $('#loginContainer').removeClass("hide");`

Comment: First toogle and then remove class. Please check my snippet.

Comment: Yup that's what I missed, the order of the toggle/remove class. Thanks very much

Comment: Sure. @EthanBristow: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Animation doesn't work with `display:none` because this not a process - it's action.

You can for example change `height/width` of element to 0, and make animation in this time, and set `display:none` on element when animation is end / user `keyup` button.

You can also animate `opacity` change - this probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    var boxOpacity = parseInt($('.box').css('opacity'));
    $('.box').animate({
        opacity: boxOpacity == 0 ? 1 : 0
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6PWN/4/

This is using opacity, not display: none;